# Django template tag accessing a queryset

Tags: django, django-templates

i have a progression  models :

```
class Progression(models.Model):
    user =  models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    started_module     =  models.ForeignKey(Module,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,)
    completedchapters =  models.ManyToManyField(Chapter)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["started_module", "user"], name="unique_module_by_user"
            )
        ]
```

in my module view i have :

```
def Module_Detail(request,module_slug):

    module = get_object_or_404(Module,slug=module_slug)
   
    context = {
        'module' :module
    }

    return render(request,'courses/module-detail.html',context)
```

in the module-detail template I want to do something like:

```
{% if module in request.user.progression_set.all.started_module %}
{{ you have already started  this module }}
{% endif %}
```

but it does  not  seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Yor variable 'module' should stay in {{ }} , Not the Plain Text with variable:

```
<span>you have already started  this {{ module }}</span>
```

Comment: i was just an exemple  the thing is  this does not work : request.user.progression_set.all.started_module

Comment: Now i understand. You can achieve started_Module objects set. I add it in answer